# Calling one Bash script from another Script passing it arguments with quotes and spaces

Tags: bash, shell, double-quotes, salt-stack

I made two test bash scripts on Linux to make the problem clear.

##### `TestScript1` looks like:

```
    echo "TestScript1 Arguments:"
    echo "$1"
    echo "$2"
    echo "$#"
    ./testscript2 $1 $2
```

##### `TestScript2` looks like:

```
    echo "TestScript2 Arguments received from TestScript1:"
    echo "$1"
    echo "$2"
    echo "$#"
```

##### When I execute `testscript1` in the following way:

```
    ./testscript1 "Firstname Lastname" testmail@example.com
```

##### The desired output should be:

```
    TestScript1 Arguments:
    Firstname Lastname
    testmail@example.com
    2
    TestScript2 Arguments received from TestScript1:
    Firstname Lastname
    testmail@example.com
    2
```

##### But the actual output is:

```
    TestScript1 Arguments:
    Firstname Lastname
    testmail@example.com
    2
    TestScript2 Arguments received from TestScript1:
    Firstname
    Lastname
    3
```

How do I solve this problem? I want to get the desired output instead of the actual output.

Comment: in a nutshell: invoke the next command with :  /path/to/TestScript2 "$@"  (see my answer, below, to see how to write TestScript1 with this requirement in mind)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Quote your args in Testscript 1:

```
echo "TestScript1 Arguments:"
echo "$1"
echo "$2"
echo "$#"
./testscript2 "$1" "$2"
```

Comment: I'm actually trying to invoke a salt-stack command which is 
salt '*mysql' cmd.run 'bash /opt/clemson/mysql/bin/test_mysql_db_create "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6"'

The double quotes don't seem to work in this case. It worked when i had the single quotes for the most part but didn't work in the case i specified in the question.

Comment: Are you saying that your real question is different from the one that you asked? :) I have no idea what a "salt-stack" command is, but it looks like you may have a problem with multiple levels of quotes. You have $1 etc enclosed in double quotes, but the whole thing is inside single quotes -- if salt-stack acts like bash, this means that you will get literal "$1" "$2" etc passed to your bash command. Perhaps you should ask a new question that is more specific to your actual situation.

Comment: My real question is different in the way that i constructed the above two test scripts showing what problem i had faced. Maybe i misinterpreted the problem. The problem is that i have made a script that executes a command in the form of salt 'servername' cmd.run 'whatever command to execute'. 
whatever command to execute is what we write on the shell for example ./testscript. It has to be included in single quotes like this './testscript'. How do i get this part to work:
'./testscript $1 $2'
that is the command is enclosed in single quotes and the double quotes aren't working inside that.

Comment: Yes, that is a different problem. You should ask a new question, with a snippet of code from your actual script. You can simplify the code that you post, but in this case you simplified it so much that it does not present the same problem that you are having.

Answer (score 45):

You need to use : `"$@"` (WITH the quotes) or `"${@}"` (same, but also telling the shell where the variable name starts and ends).

(and do NOT use : `$@`, or `"$*"`, or `$*`).

ex:

```
#testscript1:
echo "TestScript1 Arguments:"
for an_arg in "$@" ; do
   echo "${an_arg}"
done
echo "nb of args: $#"
./testscript2 "$@"   #invokes testscript2 with the same arguments we received
```

I'm not sure I understood your other requirement ( you want to invoke './testscript2' in single quotes?) so here are 2 wild guesses (changing the last line above) :

```
'./testscript2' "$@"  #only makes sense if "/path/to/testscript2" containes spaces?

./testscript2 '"some thing" "another"' "$var" "$var2"  #3 args to testscript2
```

Please give me the exact thing you are trying to do

edit: after his comment saying he attempts tesscript1 "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6" to run : salt 'remote host' cmd.run './testscript2 $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6'

You have many levels of intermediate:  testscript1 on host 1, needs to run "salt", and give it a string launching "testscrit2" with arguments in quotes...

You could maybe "simplify" by having:

```
#testscript1

#we receive args, we generate a custom script simulating 'testscript2 "$@"'
theargs="'$1'"
shift
for i in "$@" ; do
   theargs="${theargs} '$i'"
done

salt 'remote host' cmd.run "./testscript2 ${theargs}"
```

if THAt doesn't work, then instead of running "testscript2 ${theargs}", replace THE LAST LINE above by

```
echo "./testscript2 ${theargs}" >/tmp/runtestscript2.$$  #generate custom script locally ($$ is current pid in bash/sh/...)
scp /tmp/runtestscript2.$$ user@remotehost:/tmp/runtestscript2.$$ #copy it to remotehost
salt 'remotehost' cmd.run "./runtestscript2.$$" #the args are inside the custom script!
ssh user@remotehost "rm /tmp/runtestscript2.$$" #delete the remote one
rm /tmp/runtestscript2.$$ #and the local one
```

Comment: I want the command to execute like i have specified but within single quotes. Like the following way:
'./testscript2'. How do i include command line arguments $1, $2 in that?

Comment: in the above post you mentino you want to invoke: `salt '*mysql' cmd.run 'bash /opt/clemson/mysql/bin/test_mysql_db_create "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6"'` : does it mean invoking "salt" with first arg '*mysql' , 2nd arg: cmd.run , 3rd arg: 'bash......' ? and so "salt" receives as 2nd arg a string containing "$1" "$2" (and NOT their value) ? or do you want to pass their values instead?

Comment: I have two scripts. The second script accepts 7 arguments and creates a MySQL database. That script is working perfectly fine. Now i created another script to call that script through Salt Stack command. The command is salt 'target location' cmd.run 'command-goes-here'. Consider this example: 
salt '172.168.1.2' cmd.run 'ls /var/www/' so this would display me the contents of the folder /var/www present on the host 172.168.1.2. I basically want the user to invoke this script having this command which would invoke the other script that creates the database.

Comment: if the user would write ./testscript1 arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 "arg 5" arg6, then it would invoke the script which would invoke the command salt 'remote host' cmd.run './testscript2 $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6'. What this command would do is that it would do whatever is present in the section after cmd.run present between ''. So basically it would invoke testscript2 with the arguments. The problem i'm having is that i'm not able to pass properly "Firstname Lastname" as the arg5. It's not getting passed completely and is getting split. When i tried './teststring2 "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "6"' it didn't work

Comment: Instead of calling it as salt 'remote host' cmd.run "./testscript2 ${theargs}", I want to call it as salt 'remote host' cmd.run './testscript2 ${theargs}'. cmd.run takes it's argument in single quotes. Will that work?

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following to parse all arguments:

**Note** the use of `/bin/bash`

*testscript1:*

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "TestScript1 Arguments:"
echo "$1"
echo "$2"
echo "$#"

# Build PARAMS to be a list of arguments
# Each wrapped in quotes and
# any existing quotes escapes with \
for var in "$@"
do
    PARAMS="$PARAMS \"${var//\"/\\\"}\""
done

# Call the second script with eval, also passing an extra parameter.
eval ./testscript2 "ExtraParam" $PARAMS
```

*testscript2:*

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "TestScript2 Arguments received from TestScript1:"
echo "$1"
echo "$2"
echo "$3"
echo "$#"
```

Then when you execute the following:

```
./testscript1 "Firstname Lastname" testmail@example.com
```

*The output will be:*

```
TestScript1 Arguments:
Firstname Lastname
testmail@example.com
2
TestScript2 Arguments received from TestScript1:
ExtraParam
Firstname Lastname
testmail@example.com
3
```

By building the PARAMS in this way using `\"${var//\"/\\\"}\""` it allows for the script to behave correctly even if called with quotes in the arguments such as follows:

```
./testscript1 "Firstname's Last\"name" testmail@example.com
```

*Output will be:*

```
TestScript1 Arguments:
Firstname's Last"name
testmail@example.com
2
TestScript2 Arguments received from TestScript1:
ExtraParam
Firstname's Last"name
testmail@example.com
3
```

All quotes and spaces are passed from one script to the other correctly.

If you don't want all the arguments passed, miss out the for loop and just use eval with the relevant arguments.

*For example:*

```
eval ./testscript2 "\"${1//\"/\\\"}\"" "Test1" "Test2"
```

`${1...` means the 1st argument, use `${2...` for the 2nd etc.

*This will result in:*

```
TestScript1 Arguments:
Firstname's Last"name
testmail@example.com
2
TestScript2 Arguments received from TestScript1:
Firstname's Last"name
Test1
Test2
3
```

If you're sure you'll never get quotes in the argument, then don't use `"\"${1//\"/\\\"}\""` just use `"$1"`.

Answer (score -2):

I found following program works for me

```
test1.sh 
a=xxx
test2.sh $a
```

in test2.sh you use `$1` to refer variable `a` in test1.sh

echo $1

The output would be `xxx`

Comment: This wasn't the question. Please read the question carefully. Thanks