# Executing a script from a parent directory?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a root directory.

In there I have `./bin/`

In `./bin/` I have some bash scripts like:

```
launch_server.sh port=3000
```

These scripts must be ran from ./bin, that is, the working directory must be:

```
home/blah/whereever/root/bin
```

however, I would like to do:

```
cd home/blah/whereever/root/
start launch_server.sh port=3000
```

That last line would set the working directory temporarily to `./bin/` and would execute my script found in `./bin` and pass that script any arguments such as port=3000

Is this possible? What is the most convenient way I can launch my bin scripts from the root directory?

The reason is the paths need to stay relative, so I can't hardcode anything

Comment: why don't you simply do `cd home/blah/whereever/root/bin`?

Comment: @Michelem because all my other things such as rails, rake etc I run from the root directory. I want to follow that convention.

Comment: I think @Michelem is suggesting putting the `cd` in your script where you want it to change the working directory prior to invoking the next script

Comment: `start bin/launch_server.sh port=3000`?

Comment: Yes @EricRenouf or just start it with the relative path as I suggested, I can't get the problem or probably the code lacks on something we don't know

Comment: @Michelem Where does start come from, I'm suggesting having a magical launcher script called start.

Comment: It works just find if I do cd ./bin; launch_server.sh port=3000; The point is to create convenience...

Comment: Well, the root is the root of the project don't mind where a developer has it. So if you put the `start`script file in the root and inside do `start bin/launch_server.sh port=3000` it works everywhere

Comment: @Michelem My issue is I don't have the start script. I need a script that does the function of this start script.

Comment: so do you need to create the `start`script to enter the bin directory and launch `launch_server.sh port=3000` I'm almost confused...

Comment: @Michelem Yes that's exactly what I need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16988427/calling-one-bash-script-from-another-script-passing-it-arguments-with-quotes-and

Comment: Just my $0.015, but a program/library architecture that explicitly relies on current working directories and thus makes extensive (exclusive?) use of relative paths to accomplish things is unnecessarily fragile, and will in the future cause grief that would be completely avoidable with well-written software. Software should be designed and written to require making as few assumptions as possible (ideally - none) about the environment in which it is being run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1st solution:

In your `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias launch_server="home/blah/whereever/root/bin/launch_server.sh"
```

Apply the changes:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

In your `launch_server.sh` script, add before any other command:

```
cd home/blah/whereever/root/bin/
```

Now, simply call from anywhere:

```
launch_server port=3000
```

> 2nd solution:

The `start` script you want should probably look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ./bin
eval "$@"
```

Now call:

- `bash start launch_server.sh port=3000` or
- `./start launch_server.sh port=3000`

Comment: This stuff is stored on svn and there are many developers and many scripts so I need a solution that will not need to change the environment.

Comment: This solution hard codes directories. I have many svn branches and need this to work for any one of them.

Comment: What I need is a launch script where the first argument is the script name, and the rest of the args should be passed to that script.

Comment: @Milo: try the 2nd solution.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a trick by using brackets:

`cd home/blah/whereever/root/`

`(cd ./bin/ && sh launch_server.sh port=3000)`

The solution does not change your working directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in your `home/blah/whereever/root/` Directory you can run your file with

```
./bin/launch_server.sh port=3000
```

It's the common way to do so...

Comment: Is there any way to get this working like this, but not having to write the ./bin? eg: a launch script?

Comment: Where is the difference in `start launch_server.sh port=3000` and `./bin/launch_server.sh port=3000`?

Comment: The start launcher will call cd ./bin to set the environment for the scripts which expect to be launched from ./bin

Comment: Do you have multiple Files in your `{...}/bin` that have to be called this way? Or just the `launch_server.sh`