# Pass arguments to a script that is an argument to a different script

Tags: bash, shell, arguments

I am new to programming, so plz bear with the way I try to explain my problem (also any help regarding how to elegantly phrase the tile is welcome).

I have a bash script (say for example `script1.sh` ) that takes in arguments `a`, `b` and `c`(another script). Essentially, argument `c` for `script1.sh` is the name of another script (let's say `script2.sh`). However, `script2.sh` takes in arguments `d`,`e` and `f`. So my question is, how do I pass arguments to `script1.sh` ?? (example, `./script1.sh -a 1 -b 2 -c script2.sh -d 3 -e 4 -f 5`)

Sorry in advance if the above does not make sense, not sure how else to phrase it...

Comment: Check if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16988427/calling-one-bash-script-from-another-script-passing-it-arguments-with-quotes-and

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use "" for that

```
./script1.sh -a 1 -b 2 -c "script2.sh -d 3 -e 4 -f 5"
```

Try script1.sh with this code

```
#!/bin/bash

for arg in "$@"; { # loop through all arguments passed to the script
    echo $arg
}
```

The output will be

```
$ ./script1.sh -a 1 -b 2 -c "script2.sh -d 3 -e 4 -f 5"
-a
1
-b
2
-c
script2.sh -d 3 -e 4 -f 5
```

But if you run this

```
#!/bin/bash

for arg in $@; { # no double quotes around $@
    echo $arg
}
```

The output will be

```
$ ./script1.sh -a 1 -b 2 -c "script2.sh -d 3 -e 4 -f 5"
-a
1
-b
2
-c
script2.sh
-d
3

4
-f
5
```

But there is no `-e` why? Coz `echo` supports argument `-e` and use it.