# Calling a Bash script from within another bash script on Debian Buster VM

Tags: bash, alias, debian-buster

I have a script, `someutil.sh` which I would like to call in another script `main.sh`.

Both scripts are:

- In `~/bin` and are executable (`chmod +x someutil.sh`).
- Headed with `#!/bin/bash`
- Functional from the command-line

$PATH includes `~/bin` by default and `~/.bashrc` includes the aliases:

```
alias someutil="someutil.sh"
alias main="main.sh"
```

I have attempted to run `someutil` inside the script in the following ways

- someutil args (identical to usage on interactive command line)
- ./someutil args
- ~/bin/someutil.sh args

`Main.sh` executes but gives a "command not found" error for the "someutil" if I try to use the alias.

`someutil` also creates a file to use temporarily (in the home directory) which it then tries to append some data to (using `>>`, but this throws a "Permission denied error"). However, the parts where I use "`sed -i ...`" with the file as an input file work fine.

I have also tried following the advice from these answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8352939/1669825
- [Having trouble calling a bash script from another bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66354092/)

The only thing that works is to call the function using `~/bin/someutil.sh` but I would really like to use the aliases (for readability) and add the commands to the path to avoid always giving a full path. I also don't understand why the script that creates a file cannot later edit it...

So, I am clearly missing something with either the path variable (different path variables for different users or environments), or somehow not understanding which permissions the scripts run under when executed.

I am using Debian Buster on a virtual machine on a Chromebook ("Linux development environment (Beta)").

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: This might help: [using alias in shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15968053/3776858)

Comment: @Cyrus One of those answers linked a bit deeper in the thread you linked did the job, namely, regarding setting shopt -s expand_aliases and then source ~/.bash_aliases in the script itself. Thank you! I'll post an answer and reference you and the link I found via yours (or mark as duplicate?)

Answer (score 0):

Courtesy of @cyrus and [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1498/419074), the solution was to add the following to the beginning of my `main.sh` script:

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
source ~/.bash_aliases
```

Then, I could use my custom scripts the same way as in the interactive shell.

The issue regarding permissions for the temporary file was a simple, unrelated syntax error which resulted in the script attempting to execute the file instead of what was intended ([see this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1076991))