# Pop_os: how to create command-line launcher for intellij

Tags: linux, intellij-idea

On Pop_os:

when in a project folder I want to type "intellij ." and have the project open in intellij.

Official instructions say go to the main menu and use
"Tools / Create command-line launcher".... but this gives me this error

```
Launcher script creation failed: Cannot `sudo` on this system - no suitable utils found
```

Can someone help me out the maze before Voldemort takes my sanity away?

Comment: Do you have `sudo` installed? What does the terminal say when you open it and type `sudo`?

Comment: yep...sudo is present

Comment: Did you install the IDE from tar.gz or via flatpack/snap so that it's in the sandboxed environment?

Comment: flatpack/snap via Pop_Shop

Comment: Use the normal tar.gz instead: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html. `sudo` is not available inside snap.

Comment: [IntelliJ thinks it needs superuser privileges](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360006413980-Create-launcher-script-fails-with-127-on-ubuntu-18-04-LTS) "It is needed to execute system binaries, etc". Sounds fishy to me. Why would an IDE ever need root?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. This functionality is open source, go ahead and study the source code on IntelliJ IDEA Community GitHub project to see why root is needed (hint: you can't install launcher shortcut into `/usr/bin` without root).

Comment: @CrazyCoder woohoo! You have helped me escape Voldemort. Much appreciation!

Comment: @CrazyCoder "you can't install launcher shortcut into /usr/bin without root" why would I want to do such a crazy thing?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. It's a common practice to install binaries in `PATH` so that you can type `idea` and open the IDE from anywhere in the Terminal. Just convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

snap/flatpack limits access to the file system and the apps run in the sandbox, hence the problem. Use the [standard .tar.gz distribution instead](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html).

Comment: Thank you! Helped me to understand the problem. However, I would hate to re-install my intellij. Is there any chance to somehow generate *.sh manually? I thought it's just a couple of bash code lines inside *.sh file, no?

Comment: @skryvets You should be able to [call the default IDE startup script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16989110/104891) from your bash script or just create a symlink to the default startup script in PATH. See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011901879-How-to-start-IDE-from-the-command-line.

Comment: That worked! I was able to do "snap run intellij-idea-ultimate .". Thanks again!